# Why is my payment button not displaying the pop up? (Stripe)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, stripe-payments

My Stripe button isn't working. Here is the code:

```
import StripeCheckout from 'react-stripe-checkout';

export default function SignUpOne({ ... }) {
...

  const onToken = (token) => {
        console.log("onToken fired: ", token);
        handlePost(token);
    }

  return(
  ...
     <StripeCheckout
            label='Start Your Free Trial'
            
            // image='https://static.thenounproject.com/png/1259474-200.png'
            name='Native Notify Sign Up'
            description="It's free for 7 days. Then it's $29 / Month. Cancel anytime."
            panelLabel="Sign Up"
            
            currency='USD'
            locale='auto'
            stripeKey='pk_test_my-token'
            token={onToken}
            >
            <Button 
                title="Sign Up"
                color={"#06bd43"}
            />
     </StripeCheckout>
  )
}
```

Nothing is happening when I click the button. There should be a pop-up that appears on the screen.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to add the extra button tag in this case because Stripecheckout itself generate a button. Also you need to call the onToken function like this `this.onToken` . Here is the New tag for you.

```
<StripeCheckout
    label='Start Your Free Trial'
    // image='https://static.thenounproject.com/png/1259474-200.png'
    name='Native Notify Sign Up'
    description="It's free for 7 days. Then it's $29 / Month. Cancel anytime."
    panelLabel="Sign Up"
    currency='USD'
    locale='auto'
    stripeKey='pk_test_my-token'
    token={this.onToken}
></StripeCheckout>
```

Here is the result that I recieve when I run your code with above modifications

https://prnt.sc/1munr4d

Comment: Thank you. That fixed it. Do you know how to update the look of the button?

Answer (score 1):

Please be aware that the `react-stripe-checkout` package is quite outdated and uses the old "checkout" integration that is no longer recommended. Stripe recommends [migrating to the new Checkout experience](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/migration) to take advantage of all the latest features.

While this does require a server to create sessions, you can also use [Payment Links](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-links) to send your customers to Checkout with no code required.

Comment: Thank you. I might use Payment Links. It looks like a great option.